# TensorFlow Eager Execution: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_tape'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, attributeerror

I'm trying to run a custom-build model with TF in Eager Execution, but receive the error below, which I really don't know how to interpret:

```python
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-113069c95a32> in <module>()
     17     answer=tf.convert_to_tensor(answers_train[i], dtype=tf.float32)
     18 
---> 19     grads = grad(model, sent, quest, answer)
     20     optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),
     21                             global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())

<ipython-input-20-21f32f7e2b32> in grad(model, sent, quest, targets)
      2       with tfe.GradientTape() as tape:
      3         loss_value = loss(model, sent, quest, targets)
----> 4         return tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)

/Users/sdoneva/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py in __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback)
    715 
    716   def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
--> 717     tape.pop_tape(self._tape)
    718 
    719   def watch(self, tensor):

/Users/sdoneva/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/tape.py in pop_tape(tape)
     60 def pop_tape(tape):
     61   """Pops the top tape in the stack, if any."""
---> 62   pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_TapeSetRemove(tape._tape)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
     63 
     64 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_tape'
```

My inputs are arrays converted to Tensors:

```python
sent=tf.convert_to_tensor(contexts_train[i], dtype=tf.float32)
quest=tf.convert_to_tensor(questions_train[i], dtype=tf.float32)
answer=tf.convert_to_tensor(answers_train[i], dtype=tf.float32)
```

And this is how I defined my grad and loss function:

```python
def grad(model, sent, quest, targets):
      with tfe.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss_value = loss(model, sent, quest, targets)
        return tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)
def loss(model, sent, quest, y):
    prediction = model.predict(sent, quest)
    return tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y, prediction)
```

And how I call the training:

```python
grads = grad(model, sent, quest, answer)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),
                        global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
```

For the sake of completeness, here the Model:

```python
class Model(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.embed=tf.keras.layers.Embedding(42,50)
        self.grucell=tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(50)
        self.rnn=tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.grucell)
        self.dense=tf.keras.layers.Dense(42,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        self.dropout=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)

    def predict(self, sentence, question):
        encoded_sentence=self.embed(sentence)
        encoded_sentence=tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(encoded_sentence, axis=-1)  
        encoded_sentence=self.rnn(encoded_sentence)
        encoded_sentence=self.dropout(encoded_sentence)

        encoded_question=self.embed(question)
        encoded_question=tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(encoded_question, axis=-1)
        encoded_question=self.rnn(encoded_question)
        encoded_question=self.dropout(encoded_question)

        merged= tf.keras.layers.concatenate([encoded_sentence, encoded_question])
        pred= self.dense(merged)
        pred= tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(pred, axis=1)

        return pred
```

It would be great to receive some help to understand what is happening in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `tape.gradient` outside the scope of the `with` block. In particular, change your `grad` function to the following:

```
def grad(model, sent, quest, targets):
    with tfe.GradientTape() as tape:
      loss_value = loss(model, sent, quest, targets)
    return tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)
```

Comment: Indeed this was it, thanks. However for some reason the training is extremely slow compared to the same model implemented in native TF...